# Message is not displaying in <DIV> using fancybox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display message on a page using `fancybox`, but its not working. `</br>`

I am trying to use `fancybox` to open a fancy box and provide some message to the user.

I am using `JSON` to get the Users country and would like to redirect user to country
 specific site..

I can get the alert message ("Hello USA") correctly, but not the message on the page
 The message in the `<DIV>` is not appearing..I have included `JQuery` Library, Fancy Box
 `CSS` and `JS` as well. Whats is missing?
 submitting a very simple Ajax POST request to http://freegeoip.net/json to get the 
 country information,in `JSON`, and react accordingly.

I am new to Jquery.. Thanks in advance

Below is the code I have it in an HTML page:

```
   <!-- Add jQuery library --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

  <!-- Add fancyBox -->
<p>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script> 

 <script>
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
// If the visitor is browsing from Unites States.
if (location.country_code === 'US') {
alert("Hello USA");
  // Tell him about the US Site.
  jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#message'));
}
 }
} );
</script></p>
<div style="display:none;">
<div style="padding:30px;" id="message">
<h1>Hola!</h1>
<p>You are in USA, and we have a US Speific website <a href="site.com">here</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate your help

I can get the alert message ("Hello USA") correctly, but not the message on the page
The message in the  is not appearing..I have included JQuery Library, Fancy Box
CSS and JS as well. Whats is missing?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is missing. Add your JS code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ...//your code....})`

Comment: Your code is working here http://jsfiddle.net/VBg6y/1/

Comment: Hi Shaunakde.. Can you please elaborate in details in above example?  Appreciate your help

Comment: here is the page I am referring ..http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/store-wide/get-a-visitors-location - 'Trigger a popup when on the wrong website' .. Want to achive same on a separate site..the code is not executing at --  jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#message'));

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(..)`

Whenever your script/JS tries to access DOM(HTML structure) elements, the elements should be existing. So it is necessary to include `$(document).ready(..)`, so the JS code executes only after the DOM elements are loaded.

In short, a page cannot be manipulated unless the DOM is ready.

**[Refer this Link.](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (location) {
                // If the visitor is browsing from Unites States.
                if (location.country_code === 'US') {
                    alert("Hello");
                    // Tell him about the US Site.
                    jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#message'));
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBg6y/1/)**

Comment: Thanks much. I see the code is working (Demo Fiddle)..However I created a simple HTML file and its not working Here is the code

Comment: I am using these files 
<!-- Add jQuery library --> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Add fancyBox -->
<p>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet" />  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
 Followed by the Js code and DIV as in the Demo Fiddle..Whats Worng here? JQuery version?

Comment: include the css files after js.

Comment: post your current code in jsbin.com and share the link

Comment: It is working now right? Just change "IN" to "US" for your site.

Comment: just as a side note..always include all .js and .css files in `<head>` tag. And if its working dont forget to mark the correct answer

Comment: No. Still not working for me.. check full code here jsbin.com/rebuwuka/1/watch?html.. Not sure what's missing..I checked in FF, Chrome, IE8

Comment: you have still not change code form **IN** to **US** This should work http://jsbin.com/rebuwuka/2/edit

Comment: Actually I am checking from a user in IN.. User gets the alert message 'Hello' but the fancybox message does not pops up

Comment: No Error Message.. Are you able to check the code on http://jsbin.com/rebuwuka/1/watch?html